# full calendar plugin - clicked date put to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

**WORKING UPDATE:**

I'm using full calendar jQuery plugin, but I can't figure out how I can take clicked date and set it to input value.

Alert on clicked date works perfect, but it does not work when I want to move to an event or input field. Here is code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#bootstrapModalFullCalendar').fullCalendar({
            lang: 'hr',
            displayEventTime: false,
            dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
                var datum = date.format();
                alert(datum);
            },
            header: {
                left: '',
                center: 'prev title next',
                right: ''
            },
            eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
                $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
                $('#datum').html(moment(event.start._d).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                $('#fullCalModal').modal();
                return false;
            },
            events:
            [
               {
                  "title":"   Add data on this day",
                  "datum":"Date:"+moment(datum).format(),
                  "allday":"true",
                  "description":"<p><center><b>test..</b></center></p>",
                  "start":'06:00',
                  "end":'23:00',
                  "dow":'[1,2,3,4,5,6, 7]'

               }
            ]
        });
    });
```

On event click it calls modal (HTML form):

```
<div id="fullCalModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

                <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4> <!-- NASLOV -->
            </div>
            <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body"></div> <!-- OPIS  -->
        <form method="POST" name="plan" id="plan">
            <!-- POLJA ZA UNOS  -->
                <center><label for="datum">Datum:</label></center> <div id="datum" class=""></div>
                <center><input style="width:200px" autocomplete="off" style="z-index: 1;" placeholder="Datum" maxlength="100" class="form-control" type="text"  name="datum" id="datum" value="" /></center>
                <br />
                <center><label for="sifra_smjene">Šifra smjene:</label></center>
                <center><input style="width:200px" autocomplete="off" style="z-index: 1;" placeholder="Šifra smjene" maxlength="100" class="form-control" type="number"  name="sifra_smjene" id="sifra_smjene" value="" /></center>
                <br />
                <center><label for="objekt">Objekt:</label></center>
                <center><input style="width:200px" autocomplete="off" style="z-index: 1;" placeholder="Objekt" maxlength="100" class="form-control" type="number"  name="objekt" id="objekt" value="" /></center>
                <br />
                <center><label for="smjena">Smjena</label></center>
                <center><input style="width:200px" autocomplete="off" style="z-index: 1;" placeholder="Smjena" maxlength="100" class="form-control" type="number"  name="smjena" id="smjena" value="" /></center>
                <br />
        </form>

            <!-- KRAJ POLJA -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Odustani</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success font" type="submit">Spremi</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm getting clicked date: undefined / invalid date.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your JS to

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var datum;

        $('#bootstrapModalFullCalendar').fullCalendar({
            lang: 'hr',
            displayEventTime: false,
            dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
                datum = date.format();
                alert(datum);
            },
            header: {
                left: '',
                center: 'prev title next',
                right: ''
            },
            eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
                $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
                $('#datum').html(event.datum);
                $('#fullCalModal').modal();
                return false;
            },
            events:
            [
               {
                  "title":"   Add data on this day",
                  "datum":"Date:"+moment(datum).format(),
                  "allday":"true",
                  "description":"<p><center><b>test..</b></center></p>",
                  "start":'06:00',
                  "end":'23:00'
               }
            ]
        });
    });
```

You're most likely getting `undefined` because you're declaring the variable inside a function and therefore it's not accessible outside it. Declaring it as an empty variable outside it and then changing the value within should work.

Comment: Is there something for take date which is on alert? I removed "moment" but there is error: `Cannot read property 'format' of undefined`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean here?

Comment: Well, dayclick: alert returns clicked date. For example: 2017-12-10. 
I want that clicked date which alert give me into my form. 
Form now gives me: Date:2017-12-15T09:46:26+01:00 which is currently date

Comment: If you want the date that's alerted could you should just be able to change `moment(datum).format()` to `datum` if it's already formatted.

Comment: I change it to datum and it gives me Date: undefined

Comment: Right, you could also try changing `moment(datum).format()` to `moment(datum).format("YYYY-MM-DD")`. Then you're setting the formatting through Moment JS.

Comment: In the `eventClick` function you could change `$('#datum').html(event.datum);` to `$('#datum').html(moment(event.start._d).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161273/discussion-between-proofzy-and-swc).